# parseInt() is not a function

Tags: react-native

When I try to parseInt() it says:

> _this2.state.grade.parseInt is not a function

Code:

```
this.state = {grade: "1"}

let grade = this.state.grade.parseInt()
```

Does this function not work in React Native? If so how can I convert it to int?

Comment: That is the complete error.

Comment: this.state.grade is the string "1" I want to convert it to the number 1

Comment: Try Number.parseInt (this.state.grade)

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Comment: Cool. I've added it as an answer too :-)

Comment: @SinanSamet you should always pass the second, `radix`, argument to parseInt: `parseInt(this.state.grade, 10)`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
Number.parseInt(this.state.grade, 10)
// the 2nd argument is the base mathematical
// system to use for parsing and should
// always be passed to avoid confusion and
// ensure predictable behaviour
```

Comment: You should always specify the `radix` argument to parseInt. Most likely you'll want to parse the number in base 10, so a correct solution is: `Number.parseInt(this.state.grade, 10)`. For reference, see: https://davidwalsh.name/parseint-radix

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that

Comment: @DavidWalsh: thanks. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Hi, I'm changing a string with numbers using this parseInt method. At times, the string value contains ' ' (null string). If so, I need to interpret it as 0. How is this done?

Comment: @BalajiKartheeswaran `let foo = Number.parseInt((this.state.bar = '') ? 0 : this.state.bar, 10);`

Answer (score 1):

***`parseInt`*** is a global function as part of ECMAScript 2015 wich might not be vailable.

Alternatively use:

> Number.parseInt(value, base)

**base** is important because it result into different values :

**Octadecimal**

```
Number.parseInt( '011', 8)
-> 9
```

**Decimal**

```
Number.parseInt( '011', 10)
->11
```

**Hexa Decimal**

```
Number.parseInt( '011', 16)
    ->17
```